# find points in a circle with sql

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, geometry, points

I'm working on a project that has to do with poi. I store some pois in a SQL database , but before I store a poi I want to check that there is no poi with the coordinates that I have given in the database and also there is no poi with the same name and  the same type around the area of 1km , of the poi that I'm about to add. I have searched the web but I haven't figure out something help full ! Here is a part of my method that try to check if there is another poi in a radius of 1km !

PS : GPS is the name of the table

```
        for(i=0.0;i<=1.0;i=i+0.0001){
        try{
            query = "SELECT TYPE FROM GPS WHERE NAME='"+name+"' AND TYPE='"+type+"' AND     X='"+(x+i)+"' AND Y='"+(y+i)+"'";
            rs=state.executeQuery(query);
            if(!rs.next()){
                flag=1;
            }
            else{
                flag=0;
                break;
            }

        }catch(SQLException err){
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
```

Comment: You could use the "distance formula" and select everything that is 1 km away or less. Of course this does not account for curvature, but it might be a decent approximation for your needs.

Comment: provide me an example

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ignore curvature (and use a square box) you could do it a lot more efficiently in a single query, something like:

```
query = "SELECT TYPE FROM GPS 
WHERE NAME='"+name+"' 
AND TYPE='"+type+"' 
AND X < x+1 AND X > x-1
AND Y < y+1 AND Y > y-1;
```

If need be, you can then iterate through the result set and filter out pois in the box that wouldn't be in a circle with some maths.

Comment: Could you provide me also the maths ?

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring curvature, [a distance formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) can be used to find the distance between two points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2).

[image]

So, if you start with a point (A, B) and your table has columns for X and Y, this becomes:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE   root( sqr(X - A) + sqr(Y - B) ) <= 1
```

Replace "root" and "sqr" with the DB-specific functions.

Warning: In theory, this breaks down near the international date line (since longitude of 179 is close to -179), but that should not be an issue in a typical application.

Answer (score 0):

I guess a [GIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_information_system) like PostGIS could give you that functionality out of the box.

Comment: I prefer something easier !

Comment: Ok fair enough ^^ An easy implementation could be something like 'query = "SELECT TYPE FROM GPS WHERE NAME='"+name+"' AND TYPE='"+type+"' AND     X BETWEEN '"+(x-distance)+"' AND '"+(x+distance)+"' AND Y BETWEEN '"+(y-distance)+"' AND '"+(y+distance)+"';'

Comment: I don't want something that hasto do with geography ! Think simple ! Take the poi as points and I want to "create" a circle around one of them and see which of them are inside the circle and which are not !

Comment: Even simpler I used a square instead! ;)